# Exercise 35 of "learn python the hard way" NameError: global name 'dead' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, global

The "game" works fine until I "die," the error is "global name 'dead' is not defined

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")

def bear_room():
    print """There is a bear in here.
The bear has a bunch of honey.
The fat bear is in front of another door.
How far are you going to move the bear?"""
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear":
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your legs.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."

def cthulhu_room():
    print """Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane.
Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"""

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead("Well that was tasty!")
    else:
        cthulhu_room()

def start():
    print """You are in a dark room.
There is a door to your right and left.
Which one do you take?"""

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble aroudn the room until you starve.")

start()
```

Comment: Is uh, `dead()` a function you define somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

In line 58 of the provided code for lesson 35, `dead` is defined as:

```
def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)
```

If you include this in your program, you will not get that particular error message.

An error such as `NameError: global name 'dead' is not defined` indicates that you are using a global variable or function which cannot be found in your code. Hence, you need to put in into your code (or explicitly import it from an external module, depending on your situation). Either way, Python is looking for something called `dead`, cannot find it, and so gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

The function `dead()` is not defined anywhere. Check the source code carefully to make sure that it is indeed not there, or you can add one of your own, like the following:

```
import sys, time
def dead(string):
    print string
    string = string.split()
    for k in string:
        sys.stdout.write(k)
        sys.stdout.write(' ')
        time.sleep(0.25)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```